# Parse JSON dictionary inside of an array

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, swift

I am using some JSON code here. This format of parsing returns dictionaries only. I need to parse my array; [{"id":"1","Venue_Name":"Fashon Show"}]. How can I parse dictionaries from an array instead of just dictionary using this format?

```
    let urlAsString = "http://date.jsontest.com"
let url: NSURL  = NSURL(string: urlAsString)
let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

//2
let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    println(error.localizedDescription)
  }
  var err: NSError?

  // 3
  var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
  if (err != nil) {
    println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
  }

  // 4
  let jsonDate: String! = jsonResult["date"] as NSString
  let jsonTime: String! = jsonResult["time"] as NSString

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.dateLabel.text = jsonDate
    self.timeLabel.text = jsonTime
  })
})
// 5
jsonQuery.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That was easier than I expected...

Just changed jsonResult to an array,

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSArray
if (err != nil) {
println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

and changed the jsonResult inside of this code to [0]

```
let jsonDate: String! = jsonResult[0]["date"] as NSString
```